# How to change column alias in entity definition, that is used in HQL queries in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to figure out how to change column name alias used in HQL, like we can change entity name alias with `@Entity(name = "example")` annotation.

Say for example we have such entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "example")
@Table(name = "example")
public class Example {
    public Example(String exampleField) {
        this.exampleField = exampleField;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "example_field")
    public String exampleField;
}
```

Selecting by field name in *HQL* works:

```
    entityManager.createQuery("select e.exampleField from example e")
```

How to make possible selecting by **customized** column name in *HQL*, like this?

```
    entityManager.createQuery("select e.example_field from example e")
```

Notice, the second (not working, but preferred) example has `example_field` instead of `exampleField`

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not define any way to specify an alias for a persistent property, nor does Hibernate (since you mention HQL in particular) offer an extension for that purpose.  If you use field-based access, as in your example, then in your HQL queries, you must refer to entity attributes via their field names.  On the other hand, if you use property-based access then you must refer to entity attributes via names derived from the names of the annotated accessor methods.  There is no field-level analogue of the `name` attribute of the `@Entity` annotation.

> How to make possible selecting by **customized** column name in HQL

Only by naming the field on the Java side with whatever name you want to use to refer to it in your queries.  For example,

```
    @Column(name = "example_field")
    public String example_field;
```

If you happen to be subject to Java coding conventions that disallow such field names then you're stuck. There is no way to satisfy such conventions and also refer to the fields by the names you prefer in your HQL queries.